# laravel Problem with html codes appearing in content

Tags: html, laravel

https://prnt.sc/mrPjcm6osjEq

hello everyone

I am facing the error you see in the picture, how can I solve it?

```
<div class="card-body">
<p class="small">
{!! Str::limit($item->story, 120) !!}
</p>
```

code generation laravel

```
{!! !!}
```

i tried this function but the error is not resolved

Comment: I presume you are saving the HTML in your database and now you want to interpolate it as HTML on the front end in your blade file? If so, could you post an example of your database value?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: thank you for the answers I solved the problem code: {!! Str::limit(htmlspecialchars_decode($item->story), 120)